# How to set the variable in body email to run once?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, line-breaks

A body is created with a for loop. I want the `sheet.getName()` just to run once

So far, the `sheet.getName()` is looping every line. How can I make the name (battery 2 and battery 3) just to show only once? Below is the screenshot:
[image]

```
 if(resultArr.length>0){
 var subject = 'Range exceeded Alert' + "" + sheet.getName();

 //Creates a body through the obtained values

 for(var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++){
  body+= sheet.getName() + "<br>" + "For Part No "+resultArr[m] 
  [0].toString()+" and Month "+resultArr[m][1]
  .toString()+", Value is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"<br>";
            }

        }
```

I expect the `sheet.getName()` to be shown only once.

Comment: Hi, @Sriram! Please, update your question and include the part that initiates the `body` and `sheet` variable (it seems like there is an external loop that changes from Battery2 to Battery3 - is my understanding correct? (Well, Tanaike here got everything covered already :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to add `sheet.getName()` of `body+= sheet.getName() + "<br>" + "For Part No "+resultArr[m]...` only one time at the top of `body`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `body+= sheet.getName() + "<br>" + "For Part No "+resultArr[m]...` is put in the for loop. In order to add `sheet.getName()` at the top of the body, it moves `sheet.getName()` to the outside of the for loop.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

```
body += sheet.getName() + "<br>"; // Added
for(var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++){
  body+= "For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" and Month "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+", Value is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"<br>"; // Modified
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `body` is declared elsewhere.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.